# Checking for null in an object hierarchy

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a large C# (3.0) object structure originating from a deserialized XML document. I need to know whether a variable deep in the hierarchy is null. The way I do this now is to check every parent object on the way down for null, but this leads to a long repetition of if statements.

I am trying to avoid expensive try-catch blocks.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

**edit:**
For example after a deserialization of an XML application form into an object hierarchy structure there could potentially be a salary value under

```
applicationForm.employeeInfo.workingConditions.salary
```

but to find out safely I have to write something like

```
if (applicationForm.employeeInfo != null)
  if (applicationForm.employeeInfo.workingConditions != null)
    if (applicationForm.employeeInfo.workingConditions.salary != null)
```

because simply using the latter if-statement will of course fail if one of the parent objects is null.

So I am looking for any smarter way to handle this situation.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code on what you're trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Is the parent/child hierarchy of the same type? Is there a single accessor to get from base to the children? Don't you mean "check every child for null", because if a parent is null, it can't have children, it can't be accessed in the first place.

Comment: Deserializing XML is very expensive and the .NET code has many try/catch blocks already, one more wouldn't hurt. Why avoid "expensive" if "expensive" means void in relation to the rest of your code?

Comment: Is the requirement that you need to know whether a specific variable is null or whether any variable in the hierarchy is null?

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information in this question for its answers to be meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looks to me that method chaining will be helpful in your case (see my answer), because it doesn't rely on a fixed order (but touches on some advanced concepts that may be challenging if you're new to C#). Alternatively, you can use short-circuit `||` (Winston) or reflection (Wim, also advanced, and you loose type safety). Did I forget any? The recursive approaches won't fit your need but no one could know considering the bit of info that was there originally.

Comment: Good question, and I wish there was a good solution. Would be neat if one could write e.g. a:b:c to mean (a==null?null:(b==null?null:c))

Comment: How the new operator works
Consider getting the grandchild of a parent object like this:

var g1 = parent?.child?.child?.child; 
if (g1 != null) // TODO

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators

Answer (score 7):

You've run into the classic situation where each step in `A.B.C.D` may yield `null`. Though this is a common scenario, surprisingly there's no common pattern for solving it, other then using a large if-statement with lots of or's (`||`).

If each step can return a different class, then there's a rarely used pattern that you can apply: *Use a generalized generic extension method with method chaining*.

A *generalized* extension method is not a fixed term but I use it here for emphasizing that the ext. method is applicable to almost *all* types of objects, hence *generalized*. According to [Bill Wagner in Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660), this is bad design. But in some remote cases, like yours, you can use it as long as you know what you're doing and why.

**The trick** is simple: define a generic extension method and generalize it for all classes that have a default constructor. If the test fails (object is null), the method returns a new object of the same type. Otherwise, it will return the unchanged object itself.

Why is this **a good approach** for your scenario? Because you don't need to change any existing classes, because it's understandable and promotes readable code, because it keeps type safety (compile time errors instead of runtime errors) and it's simply more concise compared to other approaches.

```
// extension method:
public static class SomeExtentionMethods
{
    public static T SelfOrDefault<T>(this T elem)
        where T : class, new()     /* must be class, must have ctor */
    {
        return elem ?? new T();    /* return self or new instance of T if null */
    }
}

// your code now becomes very easily readable:
Obj someObj = getYourObjectFromDeserializing();

// this is it applied to your code:
var mySalary = applicationForm.SelfOrDefault().
    employeeInfo.SelfOrDefault().
    workingConditions.SelfOrDefault().
    salary;

// now test with one if-statement:
if(mySalary.IsEmpty())
   // something in the chain was empty
else
   // all's well that ends well :)
```

The beauty of this approach is that it works with all types of classes (provided they have a ctor), including collections and arrays. If any step is an index step, it will still work (depending on the collection, an invalid index can return null, default or raise an exception):

```
var x = 
    someObj.SelfOrDefault()
    .Collection.SelfOrDefault()
    .Items[1].SelfOrDefault()
    .Mother.SelfOrDefault()
    .Father.SelfOrDefault();
```

**Update:** expanded a bit and added a more elaborate example
**Update:** renamed <strike>`NotNull`</strike>, which implies boolean, to `SelfOrDefault`, which follows LINQ's naming convention (`FirstOrDefault` etc) and implies what it does.
**Update:** rewritten and reorganized, made code more applicable, hoping to make it more understandable overall :)

Comment: Yeah I have been taught to try and avoid method chaining.

Comment: Yet every Fluent interface is pure method chaining (FluentNHibernate, many Config APIs), the frowning comes from an extension method that's essentially available on *every* class or type: that's not good, barring some rare situations.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work without requiring a default constructor? This seems to be a big limitation.

Comment: @DaxFohl, you would want to return a (default) instance of a class to prevent the `null` from being returned instead. Without `new()`, this cannot be done with generics. An alternative would be with a static accessor, such as `MyClass.Create`, but unlike Java, .NET does not allow static members to be part of an interface, so unless you want to solve this through reflection, there is no generic way of doing it. The easy way out is to have a default ctor for each class you want to approach this way.

Comment: @James, an alternative is to use an interface, let's say `INullSafe`, which can be an empty interface (aka a _marker interface_), which could be used in the `where`-clause of the generic method above. That way you limit it only to those classes that implement `INullSafe`, but it means that you won't be able to use it with any built-in BCL classes.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, if you're repeating the logic in more than one place, encapsulate it in a method.

Secondly, you don't need lots of if statements, you just need one with a lot of OR conditions:

```
if(parent==null || 
   parent.Child == null || 
   parent.Child.GrandChild == null ...
```

Thirdly, "avoiding expensive try/catch blocks" may be a premature optimization, depending on your scenario. Have you actually tried this and profiled it, and is it really causing a large overhead?

Comment: The "avoid" try/catch is presumably to avoid using a catch to identify the case where the value is null and if that is the case then its *not* premature 'cos it is an expensive way to solve the problem

Comment: It's expensive *relative* to the cost of the proper if statement, but is it expensive enough to **matter**? If this piece of code is executed once, for example, when showing a window, then it's unlikely to make a difference, but if it's executed while rendering each ListItem in a large collection then it's probably a bad idea. So it may indeed be premature - only the OP can answer that.

Comment: I think its a bad idea to have a load of == null statements in the one if, this is a sign of recursion and would be best to implement a recursive method!

Comment: What if each level of the hierarchy was of a different type and had a different name?

Comment: Then I would rethink my design as this solution looks as though it should definetly be using recursion.

Comment: Remember, the OP referred to a hierarchy, not a tree. So it may well be something like CreateAccountRequest.Data.Account.Facilities.Statement.Format

Comment: Your structure doesn't have to necessarily need to be a tree to have a recursive solution.

Comment: I believe it would be helpful if the OP (lox, please?) took the time to help us all out here and updates his question...

Comment: The OP did update (finally). Your approach seems good advice (limits the if-statements) but my method-chaining approach &mdash; if I may call it that &mdash; seems easier to apply and read in the long run. It has the down-side of not obeying to "good coding practices" but sometimes exceptions can (and should?) be made ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can nest ternary operators. Still a pain, but not as bad as nested ifs.

```
string salary = (applicationForm.employeeInfo == null) ? null :
                (applicationForm.employeeInfo.workingConditions == null) ? null :
                applicationForm.employeeInfo.workingConditions.salary;
```

If you just want to know whether or not it is null:

```
bool hasSalary = (applicationForm.employeeInfo == null) ? false :
                 (applicationForm.employeeInfo.workingConditions == null) ? false :
                 (applicationForm.employeeInfo.workingConditions.salary != null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my simple solution:

```
if (applicationForm?.employeeInfo?.workingConditions?.salary != null)
```

Here any of these objects (applicationForm, employeeInfo, workingConditions, salary) can be null and it will resolve without error.

Answer (score 2):

can't you iterate?

```
for (SomeObject obj = someInstance; obj != null; obj = obj.Parent) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This solution assumes that the starting point is the potentially missing object, so `obj != null` would have the same effect. The problem is getting to `obj` in the first place.

Comment: Should be reversed, I guess: the last part could be `obj.Child`, but that assumes there's one accessor to get to the child and that all objects in the chain share the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection.

Create a helper method that takes a parent object and a hierarchical dot notated string for your property names. Then use PropertyInfo and use recursion to go down one property at a time each time checking for null and returning null if so, else continuing down the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't require less code than the if statement, and would be an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: Well, it's a way of doing it in a generic, reusable manner which you could apply anywhere. That's what I thought OP was after.
Regards "Order of magnitude" slower, a user wouldn't notice. Reflection is underrated. ;-)

Comment: Reflection is excellent for this type of task. I'd suggest, instead of the dot-notated string, why not simply iterate all public properties? Reflection is rather fast if you get all methods or properties at once and then iterate over them (as opposed to trying to bind by name for each name).

Comment: Was already done ;-) Now that we finally have an update to the question, I'm afraid reflection is not going to be the prettiest or type-safest solution anymore. Take a look at my method chaining example. Atm, I can't think of anything better (of course not, it's my idea!).

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide all too many details I had to fill in alot of the blanks. Here is a psuo-codeish example of how you might accomplish this via recursion

```
    public bool doesHierarchyContainANull(MyObject ParentObject)
    {

        if (ParentObject.getMemberToCheckForNull() == null)
            return true;
        else if (ParentObject.isLastInHierarchy())
            return false;

        return doesHierarchyContainANull(ParentObject.getNextInHierarchy());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked the answer by Pontus Bremdahl, but added some more detail for my uses.
Code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a member in an object hierarchy that might contain null references.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Base object to get member from.</param>
    /// <param name="getResult">Member path.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultResult">Returned object if object hierarchy is null.</param>
    /// <returns>Default of requested member type.</returns>
    public TResult SafeGet<TSource, TResult>(TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> getResult, TResult defaultResult)
    {
        // Use EqualityComparer because TSource could by a primitive type.
        if (EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default.Equals(source, default(TSource)))
            return defaultResult;
        try
        {
            return getResult(source);
        }
        catch
        {
            return defaultResult;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a member in an object hierarchy that might contain null references.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">Base object to get member from.</param>
    /// <param name="getResult">Member path.</param>
    /// <returns>Default of requested member type.</returns>
    public TResult SafeGet<TSource, TResult>(TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> getResult)
    {
        // Use EqualityComparer because TSource could by a primitive type.
        if (EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default.Equals(source, default(TSource)))
            return default(TResult);
        try
        {
            return getResult(source);
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(TResult);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
// Only authenticated users can run this code
if (!HttpContext.Current.SafeGet(s => s.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated))
        return;

// Get count limit from app.config
var countLimit = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.SafeGet(
    s => s.Get("countLimit"),
      "100" // Default 100 if no value is present
    ));

// Is int 6 a class? Always no, but just to show primitive type usage.
var is6AClass = 6.SafeGet(i => i.GetType().IsClass);
```

## Update

CSharp version 6 now has this built into it.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators

#### Null-conditional operators

Sometimes code tends to drown a bit in null-checking. The null-conditional operator lets you access members and elements only when the receiver is not-null, providing a null result otherwise:

```
int? length = customers?.Length; // null if customers is null
Customer first = customers?[0];  // null if customers is null
```

The null-conditional operator is conveniently used together with the null coalescing operator ??:

```
int length = customers?.Length ?? 0; // 0 if customers is null
```

The null-conditional operator exhibits short-circuiting behavior, where an immediately following chain of member accesses, element accesses and invocations will only be executed if the original receiver was not null:

```
int? first = customers?[0].Orders.Count();
```

This example is essentially equivalent to:

```
int? first = (customers != null) ? customers[0].Orders.Count() : null;
```

Except that `customers` is only evaluated once. None of the member accesses, element accesses and invocations immediately following the `?` are executed unless `customers` has a non-null value.

Of course null-conditional operators can themselves be chained, in case there is a need to check for null more than once in a chain:

```
int? first = customers?[0].Orders?.Count();
```

Note that an invocation (a parenthesized argument list) cannot immediately follow the `?` operator – that would lead to too many syntactic ambiguities. Thus, the straightforward way of calling a delegate only if it’s there does not work. However, you can do it via the `Invoke` method on the delegate:

```
if (predicate?.Invoke(e) ?? false) { … }
```

We expect that a very common use of this pattern will be for triggering events:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
```

This is an easy and thread-safe way to check for null before you trigger an event. The reason it’s thread-safe is that the feature evaluates the left-hand side only once, and keeps it in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckForNull(MyType element)
{
    if(element.ChildElement != null)
    {
        CheckForNull(element.ChildElement);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Null Found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function to iterate through the structure and check each node and its children for null. I was working on a sample but IE crashed (typical!!). Will post one later.

**Sample**

You could do something as simple (assuming you only ever want to just check if the structure is valid) as this:

```
public void ValidateStructure()
{
    Node root = // get the root node
    try
    {
        ValidateChildren(root);
        Console.WriteLine("All nodes are valid");
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Structure contained a null node.");
    }

}

public void ValidateChildren(Node parent)
{
    // an NullReferenceException would be raised here since parent would be null 
    foreach (var child in parent.Children)
    {
        ValidateChildren(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: using IE? Oh my, it still isn't extinct ;-)

Comment: Its really just force of habit!

Comment: @Leppie, my mistake I couldn't remember the name of it haha updated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be something like:

```
public static TResult SafeGet<TSource, TResult>(this TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> getResult) {
    if (source == null)
        return default(TResult);
    try {
        return getResult(source);
    }
    catch {
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Test myTestObject = null;
var myStringOrNull = myTestObject.SafeGet(x => x.test.test.test.mySring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Null monad.  It can be in the same file or a different file so long as you `using` it.

```
public static class NullMonad {
    public static TResult SelectMany<TIn, TOut, TResult>(this TIn @in, Func<TIn, TOut> remainder, Func<TIn, TOut, TResult> resultSelector)
        where TIn : class
        where TOut : class
        where TResult : class {
        var @out = @in != null ? remainder(@in) : null;
        return @out != null ? resultSelector(@in, @out) : null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use LINQ:

```
var salary = from form in applicationForm
             from info in form.employeeInfo
             from cond in info.workingConditions
             select cond.salary
```

This will return the salary if it exists, or null if any of the prior statements result to null, without throwing an exception.

Is it *that* much better?  No, just saves you the slightest bit of repetition, but it looks cool.  It also avoids the overhead of creating all the unused "OrDefault" objects in the accepted answer.